# Windows cmd batch loop command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, imagemagick

I have a folder structure like this:

```
my/
 1/
  jpg/
 2/
  jpg/
 3/
  jpg/

etc.
```

Now I manually run it in all folders (like 1,2,3 (in them I have jp2 files to convert)) my imagemagick command:

```
for %f in (*.jp2) do (convert %f -quality 25 jpg/%~nf.jpg)
```

But how do I write a batch file or something that will run out of `my` folder and in the loop do entering, compressing to jpg, first in `1`, then in `2`, etc.

Just for loop for directories for win cmd...

Comment: use the /f switch there are lots of examples here on SO.

Comment: @PreetSangha /f will not help

Comment: @PreetSangha you better give some code.... Or what to google

Comment: becouse for /f is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably use something like this:

```
cd my
for /d %%d in (*) do (
  for %%f in ("%%~d\*.jp2") do (
    convert "%%~ff" -quality 25 "%%~dpf\jpg\%%~nf.jpg"
  )
)
```

Comment: +1, The CD is not necessary. You could use `for /d %%d in (my\*) do ...`

Comment: i need this in .bat? also why your's is better than Preet Sangha solution?   (by it solution i get memory full error after hour)

Comment: My code is supposed to go into a batch file, yes. If you want to run it directly from the command prompt you have to replace `%%` with `%`, and perhaps add `@` before each statement to avoid command echoing: `for /d %d in ("my\*") do @for %f in ("%~d\*.jp2") do @convert "%~ff" -quality 25 "%~dpf\jpg\%~nf.jpg"`. Also I wouldn't say that my solution is per se better than what @PreetSangha suggested. It does avoid switching directories back and forth, though, because it's working with absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a higher directory

```
for /f "tokens=*"  %f  in ('dir /b/s *.jp2') do pushd "%~pf" & convert "%f" -quality 25 %~nf.jpg & popd
```

Other options:

In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
You can now use the following optional syntax:

```
    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
    %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
    %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
    %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
    %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
    %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable and expands %I to the
                   fully qualified name of the first one found.
                   If the environment variable name is not
                   defined or the file is not found by the
                   search, then this modifier expands to the
                   empty string

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

    %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
    %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
    %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
    %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable for %I and expands to the
                   drive letter and path of the first one found.
    %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line
```

remember remember to use %% instead of % when in the batch file.

Comment: error with tokens (appearing unexpectedly)  (run command in cmd)

Comment: with you last edit maybe will be good...  but i have billion of jpgs)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use a `FOR /R` loop, which is a variation of `FOR` but with recursion:

```
for /r "d:\root" %I in (*.jp2) do (convert "%I" -quality 25 "%~dpI\jpg\%~nI.jpg")
```

The `d:\root` above should be replaced with the path to your `my\` directory.

Note that you don't have to `CD` to the root directory. The above command will run fine from any location and process only the directory specified after the `/R` switch.

Also please note that the `/R` switch instructs the FOR loop to process the entire directory tree. If the tree may have folders with .jp2 files that you would like to skip, this solution will probably not work for you.

Comment: The recursive loop might process files in grandchild folders that the OP does not want to process.

Comment: In general, yes, thanks, but both the OP's folder structure and the processing command's argument line seem to suggest that there shouldn't be *.jp2 files in the grandchild folders. Still, I'll probably add an explicit note about the actual effect of the /R switch.

Answer (score -1):

Following will work

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /b /s /a-d  my') DO CALL :FileName "%%G"

Exit /b

:FileName
set str1=%~1
convert %f -quality 25 jpg/%str1%.jpg

Exit /b
```

Comment: No, it won't. `%f` is not a valid variable, `%str1%` will contain the absolute path of the file, and the script will (try to) process all files in all subdirectories, not just files with the extension `.jp2`.